# ASP.NET session state service dies with Internet Explorer 11 only

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, internet-explorer, parallels, asp.net

I'm a web developer, so I'm always checking my work on localhost. Starting a few weeks ago, if I use IE11 to connect to `localhost`, I inevitably get an error about the ASP.NET Session State server not being available.  Note that I run the service and don't use in-proc session state.  No other browsers cause this behavior.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?  It doesn't happen right at the start of the session, but typically a few pages in.  But I can now consistently re-create the problem. If I connect to my local (virtual) system from another virtual system running IE8, I don't have a problem.  I have not tried IE11 on another virtual system, so I suppose I should hesitate to blame it directly.  But it is definitely the cause locally.

System setup:
Macbook Pro running Parallels 9 with virtual systems.  Primary virtual system is Windows 7.

Comment: Maybe you're maxing out some resources somehow when IE starts.

Comment: No, resources seem fine.  It's really bizarre.  I'm hoping that someone has had a similar experience, especially since it seems to be related to the last round of updates that MS pushed.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm getting the exact same behavior. Only IE, and the service is definitely running. Once IE corrupts it, other browsers fail after that.

Comment: Nope, never really resolved it.  I think it had something to do with Fiddler, though I was (am) not able to reliably re-create the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue - when I load the website from localhost in IE, a couple of pages later it will crash the session state server, and it crashes it for all other browsers until I restart the whole computer (restarting the session state server did not help).
Mine seems to reproduce almost every time - you can't get past 3 pages without it happening.
I uninstalled Fiddler but that didn't help.

I noticed it doesn't seem to happen if you use 127.0.0.1 or the computer's IP to access the website.

With that in mind, I set the web.config setting for the state server to '127.0.0.1:42424' instead of 'localhost:42424':

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="120" mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" />
```

And it hasn't happened since :)

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I tried to re-create the issue this morning but couldn't get the service to fail, but I'll keep trying so that I can see whether your solution works.